# Is there a way to point my machine's kubectl to a K8s cluster hosted on EC2 Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, containers, kubectl

I want to point my machine's kubectl to a cluster running on EC2 instances.

When using EKS, it's fairly easy, we just need to run:

```bash
aws eks --region=<REGION> update-kubeconfig --name <CLUSTER_NAME>
```

However, how can I get the same behaviour if my master-nodes and worker-nodes are hosted on EC2 instances directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly download your cluster config from master node to your machine. Then you need to merge downloaded config with your existing config on your local.

[This](https://medium.com/@jacobtomlinson/how-to-merge-kubernetes-kubectl-config-files-737b61bd517d) post will help you how to merge them.

Then you can manage your configs with [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx).